# Koha (Library system) User Paid Fine Report

Tags: mysql

currently I'm using KOHA v23.05, in the Report module, I want to create a report which will appear the users/borrowers who paid fine (daily/monthly). Eventually I managed to pull the data of borrower number, but not their name. As per below image. The manager id and manager surname is needed to acknowledge which staff that handle the fine payment.

My question is, how can I appear the borrower (who paid fine) in this report? I'll provide the SQL codes together.

Thank you in advance, really need a help for this.

```
SELECT accountlines.accountlines_id,accountlines.borrowernumber,CAST(accountlines.amount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS formatted_amount,accountlines.date,accountlines.manager_id,borrowers.surname AS manager_surname
FROM accountlines AS accountlines
JOIN borrowers AS borrowers ON accountlines.manager_id = borrowers.borrowernumber
WHERE accountlines.credit_type_code = "Payment" AND DATE(accountlines.timestamp) BETWEEN <<From date|date>> AND <<To date|date>>
```

[Result/report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5QAy.png)

| accountlines_id | borrowernumber | formatted_amount | date | manager_id | manager_surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 353645 | 58395 | -0.60 | 2023-10-10 10:46:30 | 21 | WAN AZURA RADZUAN |
| 353646 | 58428 | -0.70 | 2023-10-10 10:56:09 | 820 | SUZYLA BINTI ABDUL AZIZ |
| 353647 | 58427 | -2.90 | 2023-10-10 10:57:38 | 820 | SUZYLA BINTI ABDUL AZIZ |
| 353648 | 58624 | -2.40 | 2023-10-10 10:58:57 | 820 | SUZYLA BINTI ABDUL AZIZ |
| 353649 | 58599 | -0.20 | 2023-10-10 11:00:53 | 820 | SUZYLA BINTI ABDUL AZIZ |
| 353660 | 1036 | -1.00 | 2023-10-10 11:32:31 | 187 | MOHD. JAMIL AHMAD MOKHTOR |

Comment: Don't post code, data or error messages as images. Post them as text. See [ask]

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Already edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a second join to the `borrowers` table to retrieve the borrower's details:

```sql
SELECT
    a.accountlines_id,
    a.borrowernumber,
    b.surname AS borrower_surname,
    CAST(a.amount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS formatted_amount,
    a.date,
    a.manager_id,
    m.surname AS manager_surname
FROM accountlines AS a
JOIN borrowers AS m ON a.manager_id = m.borrowernumber
JOIN borrowers AS b ON a.borrowernumber = b.borrowernumber
WHERE a.credit_type_code = 'Payment'
AND DATE(a.timestamp) BETWEEN <<From date|date>> AND <<To date|date>>
```